# Selenium находит элемент через раз

Tags: парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

Здраствуйте! Вытаскиваю элемент h1 на странице видео YouTube с помощью `Selenium.WebDriver` (элемент не динамичный)

```
//--- открываем ссылку
driver.Url = videoInfo.sourceUri.ToString();

//--- title - название песни
IWebElement elementH1 = FindElementByTagName(driver, "h1", out infoMessage);
```

Но при этом результат приходит через раз.  Тоесть раз находит, раз нет, потом может 5 раз находить и опять нет. Алгоритм для exception определить не удалось. У кого было подобное?!

К тому же пробовал задавать задержку в 2сек, результат тот же:

```
//--- задержка
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
```

Результат работы кода на сайте: eproves.com *(раз уж ссылку нельза оставлять)*

Comment: ссылка на сайт не относится к вопросу

Comment: @YegorAndrosov как это не относится?? А проверить вывод результата где?
Может это у меня на компе процессор слабый или т.д. Как вычеслить это по предоставленому коду?

Comment: как по ссылке определить слабый или не слабый у вас компьютер? используйте youtube api вместо селениума, падать точно не будет

Comment: @YegorAndrosov (1) Дак перейдите на сайт и проверьте работу. Если у вас будет выдодить h1. Значит в этом и дело. Думаю о алгоритмах, не мне вам рассказывать.
(2) Подскажите каким образом получить блок кода через API?

Comment: а по поводу ошибки селениума, так её надо продебажить, указать стектрейс  в вопросе, понять почему нет h1 тега, и наконец принять решение - увеличивать тайм-аут или делать retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем селениум, когда есть `youtube-dl`?

Простая команда

```
youtube-dl --get-title --get-duration --get-format \
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8waePpxD6B4"
```

выдаст три строчки:

1. название видео,
2. длительность видео,
3. формат.

[image: youtube-dl in action]

А команда полностью скачает файл:

```
youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8waePpxD6B4"
```

[image: asciicast]

Можно использовать ключ `--dump-json` для получения всех данных по видео в JSON.

Используя ключ `--format FORMAT` можно выбрать приоритетный формат для скачивания видео, или ключ `--all-formats` для скачивания всех форматов видео. А получить список форматов видео по ссылке без скачивания можно с помощью ключа `--list-formats`.

Если установлен `ffmpeg`, то можно даже сразу переконвертировать видео в нужный формат.

Там есть еще много разных опций, начиная от авторизации и установление флага о просмотренном видео, заканчивая всякими субтитрами и пакетными режимами, например, скачивание всего play-list-а или всех найденных видео на странице.

Кстати, несмотря на однозначеное название утилита `youtube-dl` поддерживает скачивание не только с Youtube и скачивание не только видеофайлов.

Полный список из 1164 поддерживаемых провайдеров текущей версии `2020.07.28` под спойлером.

> 1tv 
>   1up.com 
>   20min 
>   220.ro 
>   23video 
>   24video 
>   3qsdn 
>   3sat 
>   4tube 
>   56.com 
>   5min 
>   6play 
>   7plus 
>   8tracks 
>   91porn 
>   9c9media 
>   9gag 
>   9now.com.au 
>   abc.net.au 
>   abc.net.au:iview 
>   abcnews 
>   abcnews:video 
>   abcotvs 
>   abcotvs:clips 
>   AcademicEarth:Course 
>   acast 
>   acast:channel 
>   ADN 
>   AdobeConnect 
>   adobetv 
>   adobetv:channel 
>   adobetv:embed 
>   adobetv:show 
>   adobetv:video 
>   AdultSwim 
>   aenetworks 
>   afreecatv 
>   AirMozilla 
>   AliExpressLive 
>   AlJazeera 
>   Allocine 
>   AlphaPorno 
>   AMCNetworks 
>   AmericasTestKitchen 
>   anderetijden 
>   AnimeOnDemand 
>   Anvato 
>   aol.com 
>   APA 
>   Aparat 
>   AppleConnect 
>   AppleDaily 
>   appletrailers 
>   appletrailers:section 
>   archive.org 
>   ARD 
>   ARD:mediathek 
>   ARDBetaMediathek 
>   Arkena 
>   arte.tv:+7 
>   arte.tv:embed 
>   arte.tv:playlist 
>   AsianCrush 
>   AsianCrushPlaylist 
>   AtresPlayer 
>   ATTTechChannel 
>   ATVAt 
>   AudiMedia 
>   AudioBoom 
>   audiomack 
>   audiomack:album 
>   AWAAN 
>   awaan:live 
>   awaan:season 
>   awaan:video 
>   AZMedien 
>   BaiduVideo 
>   Bandcamp 
>   Bandcamp:album 
>   Bandcamp:weekly 
>   bangumi.bilibili.com 
>   bbc 
>   bbc.co.uk 
>   bbc.co.uk:article 
>   bbc.co.uk:iplayer:playlist 
>   bbc.co.uk:playlist 
>   BBVTV 
>   Beatport 
>   Beeg 
>   BehindKink 
>   Bellator 
>   BellMedia 
>   Bet 
>   bfi:player 
>   Bigflix 
>   Bild 
>   BiliBili 
>   BilibiliAudio 
>   BilibiliAudioAlbum 
>   BiliBiliPlayer 
>   BioBioChileTV 
>   BIQLE 
>   BitChute 
>   BitChuteChannel 
>   BleacherReport 
>   BleacherReportCMS 
>   blinkx 
>   Bloomberg 
>   BokeCC 
>   BostonGlobe 
>   Bpb 
>   BR 
>   BravoTV 
>   Break 
>   brightcove:legacy 
>   brightcove:new 
>   BRMediathek 
>   bt:article 
>   bt:vestlendingen 
>   BusinessInsider 
>   BuzzFeed 
>   BYUtv 
>   Camdemy 
>   CamdemyFolder 
>   CamModels 
>   CamTube 
>   CamWithHer 
>   canalc2.tv 
>   Canalplus 
>   Canvas 
>   CanvasEen 
>   CarambaTV 
>   CarambaTVPage 
>   CartoonNetwork 
>   cbc.ca 
>   cbc.ca:olympics 
>   cbc.ca:player 
>   cbc.ca:watch 
>   cbc.ca:watch:video 
>   CBS 
>   CBSInteractive 
>   CBSLocal 
>   cbsnews 
>   cbsnews:embed 
>   cbsnews:livevideo 
>   CBSSports 
>   CCMA 
>   CCTV 
>   CDA 
>   CeskaTelevize 
>   CeskaTelevizePorady 
>   channel9 
>   CharlieRose 
>   Chaturbate 
>   Chilloutzone 
>   chirbit 
>   chirbit:profile 
>   Cinchcast 
>   Cinemax 
>   CiscoLiveSearch 
>   CiscoLiveSession 
>   CJSW 
>   cliphunter 
>   Clippit 
>   ClipRs 
>   Clipsyndicate 
>   CloserToTruth 
>   CloudflareStream 
>   Cloudy 
>   Clubic 
>   Clyp 
>   cmt.com 
>   CNBC 
>   CNBCVideo 
>   CNN 
>   CNNArticle 
>   CNNBlogs 
>   ComedyCentral 
>   ComedyCentralFullEpisodes 
>   ComedyCentralShortname 
>   ComedyCentralTV 
>   CommonMistakes 
>   CondeNast 
>   CONtv 
>   Corus 
>   Coub 
>   Cracked 
>   Crackle 
>   CrooksAndLiars 
>   crunchyroll 
>   crunchyroll:playlist 
>   CSNNE 
>   CSpan 
>   CtsNews 
>   CTVNews 
>   cu.ntv.co.jp 
>   Culturebox 
>   CultureUnplugged 
>   curiositystream 
>   curiositystream:collection 
>   CWTV 
>   DailyMail 
>   dailymotion 
>   dailymotion:playlist 
>   dailymotion:user 
>   daum.net 
>   daum.net:clip 
>   daum.net:playlist 
>   daum.net:user 
>   DBTV 
>   DctpTv 
>   DeezerPlaylist 
>   defense.gouv.fr 
>   democracynow 
>   DHM 
>   Digg 
>   DigitallySpeaking 
>   Digiteka 
>   Discovery 
>   DiscoveryGo 
>   DiscoveryGoPlaylist 
>   DiscoveryNetworksDe 
>   DiscoveryVR 
>   Disney 
>   dlive:stream 
>   dlive:vod 
>   Dotsub 
>   DouyuShow 
>   DouyuTV 
>   DPlay 
>   DRBonanza 
>   Dropbox 
>   DrTuber 
>   drtv 
>   drtv:live 
>   DTube 
>   Dumpert 
>   dvtv 
>   dw 
>   dw:article 
>   EaglePlatform 
>   EbaumsWorld 
>   EchoMsk 
>   egghead:course 
>   egghead:lesson 
>   ehftv 
>   eHow 
>   EinsUndEinsTV 
>   Einthusan 
>   eitb.tv 
>   EllenTube 
>   EllenTubePlaylist 
>   EllenTubeVideo 
>   ElPais 
>   Embedly 
>   EMPFlix 
>   Engadget 
>   Eporner 
>   EroProfile 
>   Escapist 
>   ESPN 
>   ESPNArticle 
>   EsriVideo 
>   Europa 
>   EveryonesMixtape 
>   EWETV 
>   ExpoTV 
>   Expressen 
>   ExtremeTube 
>   EyedoTV 
>   facebook 
>   FacebookPluginsVideo 
>   faz.net 
>   fc2 
>   fc2:embed 
>   Fczenit 
>   filmon 
>   filmon:channel 
>   Filmweb 
>   FiveThirtyEight 
>   FiveTV 
>   Flickr 
>   Folketinget 
>   FootyRoom 
>   Formula1 
>   FOX 
>   FOX9 
>   FOX9News 
>   Foxgay 
>   foxnews 
>   foxnews:article 
>   FoxSports 
>   france2.fr:generation-what 
>   FranceCulture 
>   FranceInter 
>   FranceTV 
>   FranceTVEmbed 
>   francetvinfo.fr 
>   FranceTVJeunesse 
>   FranceTVSite 
>   Freesound 
>   freespeech.org 
>   FreshLive 
>   FrontendMasters 
>   FrontendMastersCourse 
>   FrontendMastersLesson 
>   Funimation 
>   Funk 
>   Fusion 
>   Fux 
>   FXNetworks 
>   Gaia 
>   GameInformer 
>   GameSpot 
>   GameStar 
>   Gaskrank 
>   Gazeta 
>   GDCVault 
>   generic 
>   Gfycat 
>   GiantBomb 
>   Giga 
>   GlattvisionTV 
>   Glide 
>   Globo 
>   GloboArticle 
>   Go 
>   GodTube 
>   Golem 
>   GoogleDrive 
>   Goshgay 
>   GPUTechConf 
>   Groupon 
>   hbo 
>   HearThisAt 
>   Heise 
>   HellPorno 
>   Helsinki 
>   HentaiStigma 
>   hetklokhuis 
>   hgtv.com:show 
>   HiDive 
>   HistoricFilms 
>   history:topic 
>   hitbox 
>   hitbox:live 
>   HitRecord 
>   hketv 
>   HornBunny 
>   HotNewHipHop 
>   hotstar 
>   hotstar:playlist 
>   Howcast 
>   HowStuffWorks 
>   HRTi 
>   HRTiPlaylist 
>   Huajiao 
>   HuffPost 
>   Hungama 
>   HungamaSong 
>   Hypem 
>   ign.com 
>   imdb 
>   imdb:list 
>   Imgur 
>   imgur:album 
>   imgur:gallery 
>   Ina 
>   Inc 
>   IndavideoEmbed 
>   InfoQ 
>   Instagram 
>   instagram:tag 
>   instagram:user 
>   Internazionale 
>   InternetVideoArchive 
>   IPrima 
>   iqiyi 
>   Ir90Tv 
>   ITTF 
>   ITV 
>   ITVBTCC 
>   ivi 
>   ivi:compilation 
>   ivideon 
>   Iwara 
>   Izlesene 
>   Jamendo 
>   JamendoAlbum 
>   JeuxVideo 
>   Joj 
>   Jove 
>   JWPlatform 
>   Kakao 
>   Kaltura 
>   KanalPlay 
>   Kankan 
>   Karaoketv 
>   KarriereVideos 
>   Katsomo 
>   KeezMovies 
>   Ketnet 
>   KhanAcademy 
>   KickStarter 
>   KinjaEmbed 
>   KinoPoisk 
>   KonserthusetPlay 
>   KrasView 
>   Ku6 
>   KUSI 
>   kuwo:album 
>   kuwo:category 
>   kuwo:chart 
>   kuwo:mv 
>   kuwo:singer 
>   kuwo:song 
>   la7.it 
>   laola1tv 
>   laola1tv:embed 
>   LCI 
>   Lcp 
>   LcpPlay 
>   Le 
>   Lecture2Go 
>   Lecturio 
>   LecturioCourse 
>   LecturioDeCourse 
>   LEGO 
>   Lemonde 
>   Lenta 
>   LePlaylist 
>   LetvCloud 
>   Libsyn 
>   life 
>   life:embed 
>   limelight 
>   limelight:channel 
>   limelight:channel_list 
>   LineTV 
>   linkedin:learning 
>   linkedin:learning:course 
>   LinuxAcademy 
>   LiTV 
>   LiveJournal 
>   LiveLeak 
>   LiveLeakEmbed 
>   livestream 
>   livestream:original 
>   livestream:shortener 
>   LnkGo 
>   loc 
>   LocalNews8 
>   LoveHomePorn 
>   lrt.lt 
>   lynda 
>   lynda:course 
>   m6 
>   mailru 
>   mailru:music 
>   mailru:music:search 
>   MallTV 
>   mangomolo:live 
>   mangomolo:video 
>   ManyVids 
>   Markiza 
>   MarkizaPage 
>   massengeschmack.tv 
>   MatchTV 
>   MDR 
>   media.ccc.de 
>   media.ccc.de:lists 
>   Medialaan 
>   Mediaset 
>   Mediasite 
>   MediasiteCatalog 
>   MediasiteNamedCatalog 
>   Medici 
>   megaphone.fm 
>   Meipai 
>   MelonVOD 
>   META 
>   metacafe 
>   Metacritic 
>   Mgoon 
>   MGTV 
>   MiaoPai 
>   MinistryGrid 
>   Minoto 
>   miomio.tv 
>   MiTele 
>   mixcloud 
>   mixcloud:playlist 
>   mixcloud:user 
>   Mixer:live 
>   Mixer:vod 
>   MLB 
>   Mms 
>   Mnet 
>   MNetTV 
>   MoeVideo 
>   Mofosex 
>   MofosexEmbed 
>   Mojvideo 
>   Morningstar 
>   Motherless 
>   MotherlessGroup 
>   Motorsport 
>   MovieClips 
>   MovieFap 
>   Moviezine 
>   MovingImage 
>   MSN 
>   mtg 
>   mtv 
>   mtv.de 
>   mtv:video 
>   mtvjapan 
>   mtvservices:embedded 
>   MuenchenTV 
>   mva 
>   mva:course 
>   Mwave 
>   MwaveMeetGreet 
>   MyChannels 
>   MySpace 
>   MySpace:album 
>   MySpass 
>   Myvi 
>   MyVidster 
>   MyviEmbed 
>   MyVisionTV 
>   n-tv.de 
>   natgeo:video 
>   NationalGeographicTV 
>   Naver 
>   NBA 
>   NBC 
>   NBCNews 
>   nbcolympics 
>   nbcolympics:stream 
>   NBCSports 
>   NBCSportsStream 
>   NBCSportsVPlayer 
>   ndr 
>   ndr:embed 
>   ndr:embed:base 
>   NDTV 
>   NerdCubedFeed 
>   netease:album 
>   netease:djradio 
>   netease:mv 
>   netease:playlist 
>   netease:program 
>   netease:singer 
>   netease:song 
>   NetPlus 
>   Netzkino 
>   Newgrounds 
>   NewgroundsPlaylist 
>   Newstube 
>   NextMedia 
>   NextMediaActionNews 
>   NextTV 
>   Nexx 
>   NexxEmbed 
>   nfl.com 
>   NhkVod 
>   nhl.com 
>   nick.com 
>   nick.de 
>   nickelodeon:br 
>   nickelodeonru 
>   nicknight 
>   niconico 
>   NiconicoPlaylist 
>   Nintendo 
>   njoy 
>   njoy:embed 
>   NJPWWorld 
>   NobelPrize 
>   Noco 
>   NonkTube 
>   Noovo 
>   Normalboots 
>   NosVideo 
>   Nova 
>   NovaEmbed 
>   nowness 
>   nowness:playlist 
>   nowness:series 
>   Noz 
>   npo 
>   npo.nl:live 
>   npo.nl:radio 
>   npo.nl:radio:fragment 
>   Npr 
>   NRK 
>   NRKPlaylist 
>   NRKSkole 
>   NRKTV 
>   NRKTVDirekte 
>   NRKTVEpisode 
>   NRKTVEpisodes 
>   NRKTVSeason 
>   NRKTVSeries 
>   NRLTV 
>   ntv.ru 
>   Nuvid 
>   NYTimes 
>   NYTimesArticle 
>   NZZ 
>   ocw.mit.edu 
>   OdaTV 
>   Odnoklassniki 
>   OktoberfestTV 
>   OnDemandKorea 
>   onet.pl 
>   onet.tv 
>   onet.tv:channel 
>   OnetMVP 
>   OnionStudios 
>   Ooyala 
>   OoyalaExternal 
>   OraTV 
>   orf:burgenland 
>   orf:fm4 
>   orf:fm4:story 
>   orf:iptv 
>   orf:kaernten 
>   orf:noe 
>   orf:oberoesterreich 
>   orf:oe1 
>   orf:oe3 
>   orf:salzburg 
>   orf:steiermark 
>   orf:tirol 
>   orf:tvthek 
>   orf:vorarlberg 
>   orf:wien 
>   OsnatelTV 
>   OutsideTV 
>   PacktPub 
>   PacktPubCourse 
>   pandora.tv 
>   ParamountNetwork 
>   parliamentlive.tv 
>   Patreon 
>   pbs 
>   pcmag 
>   PearVideo 
>   PeerTube 
>   People 
>   PerformGroup 
>   periscope 
>   periscope:user 
>   PhilharmonieDeParis 
>   phoenix.de 
>   Photobucket 
>   Picarto 
>   PicartoVod 
>   Piksel 
>   Pinkbike 
>   Pladform 
>   Platzi 
>   PlatziCourse 
>   play.fm 
>   PlayPlusTV 
>   PlaysTV 
>   Playtvak 
>   Playvid 
>   Playwire 
>   pluralsight 
>   pluralsight:course 
>   plus.google 
>   podomatic 
>   Pokemon 
>   PolskieRadio 
>   PolskieRadioCategory 
>   Popcorntimes 
>   PopcornTV 
>   PornCom 
>   PornerBros 
>   PornHd 
>   PornHub 
>   PornHubPagedVideoList 
>   PornHubUser 
>   PornHubUserVideosUpload 
>   Pornotube 
>   PornoVoisines 
>   PornoXO 
>   PornTube 
>   PressTV 
>   prosiebensat1 
>   puhutv 
>   puhutv:serie 
>   Puls4 
>   Pyvideo 
>   qqmusic 
>   qqmusic:album 
>   qqmusic:playlist 
>   qqmusic:singer 
>   qqmusic:toplist 
>   QuantumTV 
>   Quickline 
>   QuicklineLive 
>   R7 
>   R7Article 
>   radio.de 
>   radiobremen 
>   radiocanada 
>   radiocanada:audiovideo 
>   radiofrance 
>   RadioJavan 
>   Rai 
>   RaiPlay 
>   RaiPlayLive 
>   RaiPlayPlaylist 
>   RayWenderlich 
>   RayWenderlichCourse 
>   RBMARadio 
>   RDS 
>   RedBullTV 
>   RedBullTVRrnContent 
>   Reddit 
>   RedditR 
>   RedTube 
>   RegioTV 
>   RENTV 
>   RENTVArticle 
>   Restudy 
>   Reuters 
>   ReverbNation 
>   RICE 
>   RMCDecouverte 
>   RockstarGames 
>   RoosterTeeth 
>   RottenTomatoes 
>   Roxwel 
>   Rozhlas 
>   RTBF 
>   rte 
>   rte:radio 
>   rtl.nl 
>   rtl2 
>   rtl2:you 
>   rtl2:you:series 
>   Rtmp 
>   RTP 
>   RTS 
>   rtve.es:alacarta 
>   rtve.es:infantil 
>   rtve.es:live 
>   rtve.es:television 
>   RTVNH 
>   RTVS 
>   RUHD 
>   rutube 
>   rutube:channel 
>   rutube:embed 
>   rutube:movie 
>   rutube:person 
>   rutube:playlist 
>   RUTV 
>   Ruutu 
>   Ruv 
>   safari 
>   safari:api 
>   safari:course 
>   SAKTV 
>   SaltTV 
>   Sapo 
>   savefrom.net 
>   SBS 
>   schooltv 
>   screen.yahoo:search 
>   Screencast 
>   ScreencastOMatic 
>   ScrippsNetworks 
>   scrippsnetworks:watch 
>   SCTE 
>   SCTECourse 
>   Seeker 
>   SenateISVP 
>   SendtoNews 
>   Servus 
>   Sexu 
>   SeznamZpravy 
>   SeznamZpravyArticle 
>   Shahid 
>   ShahidShow 
>   Shared 
>   ShowRoomLive 
>   Sina 
>   SkylineWebcams 
>   SkyNews 
>   skynewsarabia:article 
>   skynewsarabia:video 
>   SkySports 
>   Slideshare 
>   SlidesLive 
>   Slutload 
>   smotri 
>   smotri:broadcast 
>   smotri:community 
>   smotri:user 
>   Snotr 
>   Sohu 
>   SonyLIV 
>   soundcloud 
>   soundcloud:playlist 
>   soundcloud:search 
>   soundcloud:set 
>   soundcloud:trackstation 
>   soundcloud:user 
>   SoundcloudEmbed 
>   soundgasm 
>   soundgasm:profile 
>   southpark.cc.com 
>   southpark.cc.com:español 
>   southpark.de 
>   southpark.nl 
>   southparkstudios.dk 
>   SpankBang 
>   SpankBangPlaylist 
>   Spankwire 
>   Spiegel 
>   Spiegel:Article 
>   Spiegeltv 
>   sport.francetvinfo.fr 
>   Sport5 
>   SportBox 
>   SportDeutschland 
>   SpringboardPlatform 
>   Sprout 
>   sr:mediathek 
>   SRGSSR 
>   SRGSSRPlay 
>   stanfordoc 
>   Steam 
>   Stitcher 
>   Streamable 
>   streamcloud.eu 
>   StreamCZ 
>   StreetVoice 
>   StretchInternet 
>   stv:player 
>   SunPorno 
>   sverigesradio:episode 
>   sverigesradio:publication 
>   SVT 
>   SVTPage 
>   SVTPlay 
>   SVTSeries 
>   SWRMediathek 
>   Syfy 
>   SztvHu 
>   t-online.de 
>   Tagesschau 
>   tagesschau:player 
>   Tass 
>   TastyTrade 
>   TBS 
>   TDSLifeway 
>   Teachable 
>   TeachableCourse 
>   teachertube 
>   teachertube:user:collection 
>   TeachingChannel 
>   Teamcoco 
>   TeamTreeHouse 
>   TechTalks 
>   techtv.mit.edu 
>   ted 
>   Tele13 
>   Tele5 
>   TeleBruxelles 
>   Telecinco 
>   Telegraaf 
>   TeleMB 
>   TeleQuebec 
>   TeleQuebecEmission 
>   TeleQuebecLive 
>   TeleQuebecSquat 
>   TeleTask 
>   Telewebion 
>   TennisTV 
>   TenPlay 
>   TestURL 
>   TF1 
>   TFO 
>   TheIntercept 
>   ThePlatform 
>   ThePlatformFeed 
>   TheScene 
>   TheStar 
>   TheSun 
>   TheWeatherChannel 
>   ThisAmericanLife 
>   ThisAV 
>   ThisOldHouse 
>   TikTok 
>   TikTokUser 
>   tinypic 
>   TMZ 
>   TMZArticle 
>   TNAFlix 
>   TNAFlixNetworkEmbed 
>   toggle 
>   ToonGoggles 
>   Tosh 
>   tou.tv 
>   Toypics 
>   ToypicsUser 
>   TrailerAddict (CURRENTLY BROKEN) 
>   Trilulilu 
>   TruNews 
>   TruTV 
>   Tube8 
>   TubiTv 
>   Tumblr 
>   tunein:clip 
>   tunein:program 
>   tunein:shortener 
>   tunein:station 
>   tunein:topic 
>   TunePk 
>   Turbo 
>   tv.dfb.de 
>   TV2 
>   tv2.hu 
>   TV2Article 
>   TV2DK 
>   TV2DKBornholmPlay 
>   TV4 
>   TV5MondePlus 
>   TVA 
>   TVANouvelles 
>   TVANouvellesArticle 
>   TVC 
>   TVCArticle 
>   tvigle 
>   tvland.com 
>   TVN24 
>   TVNet 
>   TVNoe 
>   TVNow 
>   TVNowAnnual 
>   TVNowNew 
>   TVNowSeason 
>   TVNowShow 
>   tvp 
>   tvp:embed 
>   tvp:series 
>   TVPlayer 
>   TVPlayHome 
>   Tweakers 
>   TwitCasting 
>   twitch:chapter 
>   twitch:clips 
>   twitch:profile 
>   twitch:stream 
>   twitch:video 
>   twitch:videos:all 
>   twitch:videos:highlights 
>   twitch:videos:past-broadcasts 
>   twitch:videos:uploads 
>   twitch:vod 
>   twitter 
>   twitter:amplify 
>   twitter:broadcast 
>   twitter:card 
>   udemy 
>   udemy:course 
>   UDNEmbed 
>   UFCArabia 
>   UFCTV 
>   UKTVPlay 
>   umg:de 
>   UnicodeBOM 
>   Unistra 
>   Unity 
>   uol.com.br 
>   uplynk 
>   uplynk:preplay 
>   Urort 
>   URPlay 
>   USANetwork 
>   USAToday 
>   ustream 
>   ustream:channel 
>   ustudio 
>   ustudio:embed 
>   Varzesh3 
>   Vbox7 
>   VeeHD 
>   Veoh 
>   Vesti 
>   Vevo 
>   VevoPlaylist 
>   VGTV 
>   vh1.com 
>   vhx:embed 
>   Viafree 
>   vice 
>   vice:article 
>   vice:show 
>   Vidbit 
>   Viddler 
>   Videa 
>   video.google:search 
>   VideoDetective 
>   videofy.me 
>   videomore 
>   videomore:season 
>   videomore:video 
>   VideoPress 
>   Vidio 
>   VidLii 
>   vidme 
>   vidme:user 
>   vidme:user:likes 
>   Vidzi 
>   vier 
>   vier:videos 
>   viewlift 
>   viewlift:embed 
>   Viidea 
>   viki 
>   viki:channel 
>   vimeo 
>   vimeo:album 
>   vimeo:channel 
>   vimeo:group 
>   vimeo:likes 
>   vimeo:ondemand 
>   vimeo:review 
>   vimeo:user 
>   vimeo:watchlater 
>   Vimple 
>   Vine 
>   vine:user 
>   Viqeo 
>   Viu 
>   viu:ott 
>   viu:playlist 
>   Vivo 
>   vk 
>   vk:uservideos 
>   vk:wallpost 
>   vlive 
>   vlive:channel 
>   vlive:playlist 
>   Vodlocker 
>   VODPl 
>   VODPlatform 
>   VoiceRepublic 
>   Voot 
>   VoxMedia 
>   VoxMediaVolume 
>   vpro 
>   Vrak 
>   VRT 
>   VrtNU 
>   vrv 
>   vrv:series 
>   VShare 
>   VTXTV 
>   vube 
>   VuClip 
>   VVVVID 
>   VyboryMos 
>   Vzaar 
>   Wakanim 
>   Walla 
>   WalyTV 
>   washingtonpost 
>   washingtonpost:article 
>   wat.tv 
>   WatchBox 
>   WatchIndianPorn 
>   WDR 
>   wdr:mobile 
>   WDRElefant 
>   WDRPage 
>   Webcaster 
>   WebcasterFeed 
>   WebOfStories 
>   WebOfStoriesPlaylist 
>   Weibo 
>   WeiboMobile 
>   WeiqiTV 
>   Wistia 
>   wnl 
>   WorldStarHipHop 
>   WSJ 
>   WSJArticle 
>   WWE 
>   XBef 
>   XboxClips 
>   XFileShare 
>   XHamster 
>   XHamsterEmbed 
>   XHamsterUser 
>   xiami:album 
>   xiami:artist 
>   xiami:collection 
>   xiami:song 
>   ximalaya 
>   ximalaya:album 
>   XMinus 
>   XNXX 
>   Xstream 
>   XTube 
>   XTubeUser 
>   Xuite 
>   XVideos 
>   XXXYMovies 
>   Yahoo 
>   yahoo:gyao 
>   yahoo:gyao:player 
>   yahoo:japannews 
>   YandexDisk 
>   yandexmusic:album 
>   yandexmusic:playlist 
>   yandexmusic:track 
>   YandexVideo 
>   YapFiles 
>   YesJapan 
>   yinyuetai:video 
>   Ynet 
>   YouJizz 
>   youku 
>   youku:show 
>   YouNowChannel 
>   YouNowLive 
>   YouNowMoment 
>   YouPorn 
>   YourPorn 
>   YourUpload 
>   youtube 
>   youtube:channel 
>   youtube:favorites 
>   youtube:history 
>   youtube:live 
>   youtube:playlist 
>   youtube:playlists 
>   youtube:recommended 
>   youtube:search 
>   youtube:search:date 
>   youtube:search_url 
>   youtube:show 
>   youtube:subscriptions 
>   youtube:truncated_id 
>   youtube:truncated_url 
>   youtube:user 
>   youtube:watchlater 
>   Zapiks 
>   Zaq1 
>   Zattoo 
>   ZattooLive 
>   ZDF 
>   ZDFChannel 
>   zingmp3 
>   Zype

В этом списке провайдеров есть все известные мне российские хостинги видео.

Вы точно уверены, что вам нужен селениум?

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Действительно не знал об этой технологии.
Можно с помощью его парсить динамические элементы? К примеру после клика?